# why does extraction of this ZIP archive fail?

Tags: java

I've written the following method to create a ZIP archive

```
public class ZipUtils {
    public static byte[] createZipArchive(Collection<FileWrapper> sourceFiles) throws IOException {

        try (var bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); var zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(bytesOut)) {

            for (var sourceFile : sourceFiles) {
                try (var fileContent = sourceFile.getResource().getInputStream()) {

                    var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(sourceFile.getFileName());
                    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fileContent.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                        zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                    }
                }
            }
            zipOut.flush();
            return bytesOut.toByteArray();
        }
    }
}
```

`FileWrapper` is a simple data class that encapsulates a file's content and it's name

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class FileWrapper {
    private final String fileName;
    private final Resource resource;

    // getters, setters, constructors omitted
}
```

I've written the following unit test

```
public class ZipUtilsTests {

    @Test
    void createZipArchive() throws IOException {
        var file1 = getFile("src/test/resources/json/event.json");
        var file2 = getFile("src/test/resources/json/label.json");
        var zipData = ZipUtils.createZipArchive(Set.of(file1, file2));

        File zipOutput = File.createTempFile("2-json-files", ".zip");
        logger.debug("Writing ZIP archive to: " + zipOutput.getAbsolutePath());
        Files.write(zipOutput.toPath(), zipData);
    }

    private FileWrapper getFile(String path) throws IOException {
        var bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        var resource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes);
        var fileName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(path, '/');
        return new FileWrapper(fileName, resource);
    }
}
```

If I navigate to the ZIP file this test creates and try to unzip it, I get the following error

[image]

The size of the file is roughly what I would expect, but there's obviously something wrong with it because extraction of the files fails.

Comment: Not sure but you don't flush and you don't close zipOut before returning the byte array. Perhaps you need to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to flush your outstream at the end of the try?

Comment: @ewramner `zipOut` will be closed automatically https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html because it's declared within a try-with-resources block

Comment: @AntonioDragos it will, but AFTER you have returned bytesOut.toByteArray(). Try changing the code so that zipOut is closed BEFORE you return the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
try(var bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) { 
        
    try (var zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(bytesOut)) {
        for (var sourceFile : sourceFiles) {
            try (var fileContent = sourceFile.getResource().getInputStream()) {

                var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(sourceFile.getFileName());
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fileContent.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bytesOut.toByteArray();
        
}
```

You need that zipOut is closed before you return byte array.

I hope help you

Comment: The first `try` statement isn’t needed.  [Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream does nothing.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close())

Answer (score 1):

just add:

```
zipOut.closeEntry();
zipOut.close();
```

before `return bytesOut.toByteArray();`

Done.

Comment: This will work... for now, but amounts to closing twice the ZIPping output stream, which I would argue is a code smell. There is a try with resources that will close the output stream, by closing it manually inside this block, one can only wonder where the "real" close is intended to be. This works as long as every stream is self contained in the method, but a few month from now, somebody modifying the method (e.g. write to a file, to a servlet response, whatever, by argument) and doing something clever (teeing, logging, shield-closing) will have to work this out.